# How can we verify this limit via $\epsilon-\delta$ method?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Say I have to calculate the limit

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1 - \cos(x)}{3\sin^2(x)}$$

Now, from the use of De l'Hôpital rule (or other methods like notable special limits), we know the limit is $\dfrac{1}{6}$.

Let's say we want to verify it by the definition. Hence

$$\big|\dfrac{1 - \cos(x)}{3\sin^2(x)} - \frac{1}{6}\big| < \epsilon$$

$$\big|\dfrac{2 - 2\cos(x) - \sin^2(x)}{6\sin^2(x)}\big| < \epsilon$$

What would come into my mind is to use estimations but this wouldn't work because I am not treating a succession (where $n\to+\infty$ hence I can use $|\sin(n)| = 1$ and similar trick).

So how would one reason with a case like this?

I tried to rewrite the numerator in cosine terms only, and then I managed to rewrite it as

$$1 - 2\cos(x) + \cos^2(x) \to (\cos(x) - 1)^2$$

forgetting about periodicity of the solutions (the associate equation $y^2 - 2y + 1 = 0$ would give $t = 1$ hence $x = \frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi$ as a solution), so:

$$\big|\dfrac{(\cos(x)-1)^2}{6\sin^2(x)}\big| < \epsilon$$

But now the absolute value is meaningless since numerator and denominator are always positive (?), so how to proceed?

Comment: Do you know the limits of $\frac {1-\cos x } {x^{2}}$ and $\frac {\sin x } x$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, that doesn't answer to my question though. I need to VERIFY the limit via the definition $\epsilon-\delta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$
We have to show that
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta \in (0, \pi/2]: \forall x \in \R\setminus\{0\}: (|x| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)| < \epsilon)
$$
where
$$
f(x) = \dfrac{(1 - \cos x)^2}{6 \sin^2 x}
=
\dfrac{(1 - \cos x)^2}{6(1- \cos^2 x)}
$$
Let $ t = \cos x$. Then, because $ t \neq 1 $ whenever $x \neq 0$ and $ |x| < \pi/2 $,

$$
f(x)
= \dfrac{(1 - t)^2}{6(1- t^2)}
= \dfrac{(1 - t)}{6(1 + t)}
= \dfrac{(2 -1 - t)}{6(1 + t)}
= \dfrac{1}{3(1 + t)} - \dfrac{1}{6}
$$
$f(x)$ strictly decreases w.r.t. $t$.

Find $t$ that makes $f(x) = \epsilon$. After all, $t = 2/(6\epsilon + 1) - 1$. Since $ t = \cos x$,
choosing

$$
\delta = \arccos \left(\dfrac{2}{6\min\{\epsilon, 1/6\} + 1} - 1 \right) 
$$
proves the claim. I think you can show that $\delta$ is an increasing function of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

You can also multiply and divide by $1+\cos x$:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos x}{3 \sin^2 x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos^2 x}{3\sin^2 x (1+\cos x)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{3\sin^2 x (1+\cos x)}
=\frac 13 \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1+\cos x}= \frac 16$$

---

If you need to use the definition, you can easily see that
$$
\left| \frac{1-\cos x}{3 \sin^2 x}-\frac  16\right|=\frac 13 \left|\frac{1}{1+\cos x}-\frac 12 \right| \to 0 \quad (x \to 0)
$$

Since there is no indetermination in this limit, you can use Heine's definition in a very straightforward way (instead of Cauchy's). Or, you can go on to obtain
$$
\left|\frac{1}{1+\cos x}-\frac 12 \right| = \frac 12 \left|\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x} \right| \leq \frac 12 |1-\cos x|\leq \frac 12 |x| 
$$

Comment: That doesn't answer to my question, actually...

Comment: Hence the "also"... But you can use the same simplification when bounding $|f(x)-\frac 16|$.

Comment: Uh, pardon! I misread too quickly!

Comment: @Hans-André-Marie-Stamm I edited my answer to include the use of Heine's or Cauchy's definition of limit.